# Sum vector of integer using MPI c

Tags: c++, mpi

I want to sum vector of integer using MPI.

Let's assume I have a vector a with 20 elements and a vector b with 20 elements too and I want to sum them in a vector c.

The rank 0 will send parts of the vector a and b to another rank,that will calculate the sum and then return another vector with the answer to rank 0. and so on.

The point is, the values that are passed between the ranks (process) is not working. Should I use pointer? What should I do.?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num; 
  int mpi_myrank, mpi_size, mpi_tag, mpi_from = 0;
  MPI::Status mpi_status;

  MPI::Init(argc, argv);
  mpi_myrank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  mpi_size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();


     int a[20];
     int b[20];
     int c[20];
     int delta = 5; // seria n / size = 5
     int size=4;
     int *buffer; 
     buffer = (int*) malloc(delta*sizeof(int)); 
     for(int i = 0 ; i<20;i++){
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
    }




  if (mpi_myrank == 0) {
    mpi_tag = 100;
    for(int i=1 ; i<size ; i++){

        for(int j=0 ; j<delta ; j++){   
            buffer[j] = a[(delta*i) +j];    
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&buffer,delta, MPI::INT, i, mpi_tag); 
        }
        for(int j=0 ; j<delta ; j++){   
            buffer[j] = b[(delta*i) +j];
             MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&buffer,delta, MPI::INT, i, mpi_tag); 
        }

    }

    for(int j=0; j<delta;j++ ){
        c[j] = a[j] + b[j];
    }

    for(int i=1; i<size;i++) {
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&buffer, delta, MPI::INT, i, mpi_tag, mpi_status); 
        for(int j=0 ; j<delta;j++){
            c[(delta*i) + j] = buffer[j];       
        }
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++){
        cout << "posicao " << i << " igual a " << c[i] << endl;
    }


}

  else {
    mpi_tag = 100;
    //int *bufa; 
    //bufa = (int*) malloc(delta*sizeof(int)); 
    //int *bufb; 
    //bufb = (int*) malloc(delta*sizeof(int));

    int bufa[delta];
    int bufb[delta];
    int resp[delta];
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&bufa, delta, MPI::INT, 0, mpi_tag, mpi_status);   
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&bufb, delta, MPI::INT, 0, mpi_tag, mpi_status);

    for(int i=0; i<delta ;i++){
        resp[delta] = bufa[i] + bufb[i]; 
    }   

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&resp,delta, MPI::INT, 0, mpi_tag);

  } // fim else

  MPI::Finalize();
  return 0;
} // fim main
```

Comment: A side note: Have you considered using scatter and gather functions?

Comment: No.

i haven't, actually I am new using MPI.

The point is, the communication is working, but the values passed between them is not totally correct. Sometimes in position 0 shows a value like 1038193891829

Comment: I haven't looked over your code, but most probably you have got the indices wrong. Double check them! Anyway, scatter and gather would save you a for loop each and manual calculation of indices.

Comment: You've got the arguments to send and receive wrong - `&buffer` should be `buffer` instead, otherwise you are sending the address contained in the pointer instead of the data that it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code looks incorrect

```
for(int i=0; i<delta ;i++){
    resp[delta] = bufa[i] + bufb[i]; 
}
```

You are overwriting the same position of the array in a loop, meaning the other positions may have garbage values.

Comment: exactly.... 

I found it yesterday night. 

That's exactly what you said. 

Thanks